# Fields are cleared when update p:tabView

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, tabs, primefaces

I have a popup with three tabs in primefaces tabPanel. In the middle is a table called "composicao", this tab is rendered when user marks checkbox that is located in first tab.
The tables have a lot of inputs, selects and checkboxes that user can fill in any order, so if the user fill all fields and then mark the checkbox, all fields are cleared cause that checkbox update the tabView. I tryied  set some fields immediate attribute to true and set p:ajax process attribute to @all, but with this approach nothing happens.

This is the code of tabPanel:

```
<h:panelGroup id="abasCadastroProduto">
        <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="base">
                <ui:include src="../../tabs/abaEdicaoBaseProduto.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="abaComposicao" title="composicao" rendered="#{produto.composto}">
                <ui:include src="../../tabs/abaEdicaoComposicaoProduto.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab
                    title="tributacao">
                <ui:include src="../../tabs/abaEdicaoTributacaoProduto.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

this is part of the code of first tab:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
<p:fieldset legend="geral">
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="produtoAtivoCheck"
                             value="#{produto.ativo}"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="ativo" for="produtoAtivoCheck"/>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="produtoMovimentoCheck"
                             value="#{produto.movimentaEstoque}"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="movimento" for="produtoMovimentoCheck"/>

    <!-- THIS IS THE CHECKBOX -->
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="produtoCompostoCheck"
                             value="#{produto.composto}">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="abasCadastroProduto" process="@all"/>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

    <h:outputLabel value="composto" for="produtoCompostoCheck" />
</h:panelGroup>
.......
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <h:outputLabel value="descricao"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{produto.descricao}" required="true" immediate="true"
                 requiredMessage="obrigatorio"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="complemento"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{produto.descricaoComplementar}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
......
</p:fieldset>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Is there a way I can solve this problem??
I think is unnaceptable to user see fields they spend some time to fill, been cleared when you click in a checkbox...

Comment: Perhaps a validation error is occurring somewhere in the form and that is causing the values to not update themselves?  Do you have a situation with nested forms?  Is your form prepending its id onto child elements?  Perhaps the panelGroup id is actually `form:abasCadastroProduto` and thus it is not actually getting updated?  It is impossible to tell unless we see all the code.

Comment: Can you delete all the unnecessary code like `styleClass`, etc? And can you also highlight which checkbox caused the problem?

Comment: Yes form is prepending id...
But I believe the problem could be validation, this form has a lot of required fields, but I didn't received any required field message...

Comment: @brevleq Make sure that your update attribute is appropriate then, `update='form:abasCadastroProduto'` on the checkbox.

Comment: @maple_shaft I've already tryied use complete id, and got the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
The problem was validation of required fields, so I've created a REQUIRED parameter and set it to false when user clicks checkbox:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="produtoCompostoCheck"
                     value="#{produto.composto}" styleClass="popup-produto-geral-check">
        <f:param name="REQUIRED" value="false"/>
        <f:ajax event="change" immediate="true" render="abasCadastroProduto" execute="@form" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{produto.idClasse}" immediate="true"
                     required="#{param['REQUIRED']}" validatorMessage="#{cadastroMsg['popup.cadastro.produto.base.classe.invalido']}"
                     requiredMessage="#{cadastroMsg['popup.cadastro.produto.base.classe.obrigatorio']}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectItemClasse.itens}"/>
        <f:ajax event="change" immediate="true" render="selectSubclasse"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and I've made submit button set "REQUIRED" parameter to true.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="abasCadastroProduto" process="@all"/>
```

try this:

```
<p:ajax render="@form" />
```

Comment: The `<p:ajax>` doesn't have this attribute.